# Name of graph partition that balances edges between sets with edges remaining within sets

Tags: graph-theory, max-cut, max-flow-min-cut

Is there a common name for this problem:

Let G=(V, E) be an undirected graph.  Partition V into sets $S_1$, $S_2$, ..., $S_k$, such that (the number of edges between sets) + (the number of "non"-edges within sets) is minimized.

To be clear: define "extra edges" to be the set of edges with endpoints in different sets; define "missing edges" to be the set of edges in the complement of G with endpoints in the same set.  The goal is to find a partition that minimizes the sum of "extra edges" and "missing edges".

(The sets need not be of similar size.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Min-Disagreements version of the correlation clustering problem (on complete graphs), defined by [Bansal, Blum, and Chawla](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/Papers/clustering.ps) ([full version](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:MACH.0000033116.57574.95)). They give a (huge) constant factor approximation for the problem and prove it's NP-hard. [Charikar, Guruswami, and Wirth](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse522/05au/charikarcorrelation.pdf) show the problem is APX-hard, and improve the approximation factor to 4 via region growing. There is a beautiful and simple combinatorial algorithm (a variant of QuickSort), due to [Ailon, Charikar, and Newman](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~alantha/papers2/aggregating_journal.pdf), that gives a factor 3 approximation. I believe the current best known approximation ratio is due to [Chawla, Makarychev, Schramm, and Yaroslavtsev](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.0681v3.pdf), and is around 2.06.

Comment: It's worth noting that the value of $k$ (the number of clusters) is _not_ part of the input for correlation clustering; the algorithm is free to choose whatever number of clusters it thinks is best.

Comment: @AndrewMorgan that's a good point

Comment: Are there any implementations of the approximation algorithms available (perhaps either Demaine and Immorlica or Emanuel and Fiat)?

Comment: I know the region growing algorithm was implemented in the context of modularity maximization [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~dkempe/publications/clustering.zip). It's also not a difficult algorithm to code up, as long as you get yourself an LP solver, although the LP is unfortunately quite big. The quick-sort based algorithm is simpler, and doesn't require solving an LP.

Answer (score 2):

In the parameterized complexity community, it is called cluster editing. See e.g. "Cluster graph modification problems", Ron Shamir, Roded Sharan and Dekel Tsur, Discrete Applied Mathematics 2004, [doi:10.1016/j.dam.2004.01.007](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2004.01.007), "Efficient Parameterized Preprocessing for Cluster Editing", Michael Fellows, Michael Langston, Frances Rosamond, and Peter Shaw, FCT 2007, [doi:10.1007/978-3-540-74240-1_27](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-74240-1_27), and [this related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3690/a-multi-cut-problem/3698#3698).